# How to take values out of a pandas dataframe and put them into a numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple pandas dataframes and I would like to write a function that will take out the values in each column of the dataframes and put them into their own numpy array.

Example dataframe

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    A  B
 0  1  2
 1  1  3
 2  4  6
```

How would I generate two different numpy arrays out of the values in column A and B

Comment: Just use `df.values`;

Comment: doesn't that take the values from the whole dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I edited my question. Any other ways I could improve it?

Comment: What is your expected output? A list of numpy array?

Comment: The expected output would be a numpy array. I can take a column and convert it to an numpy array using df.iloc and then coverting that us np.asarray but I was wondering what would be the best way to write a function that does that because I have a couple dataframes and they're all different lengths

Answer (score 1):

`df['A'].values` will return numpy arrays. see below:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col, type(df[col].values))
A <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
B <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to obtain a list of numpy arrays for each column. You can put the arrays in a dictionary too but I prefer a list over the former because it is ordered and we can always use a zip function with df.columns to get tupled data!

```
np_arr_list = []
for i in df.columns:
    new_np_arr = np.array(df.loc[:,i])
    np_arr_list.append(new_np_arr)
```

Output:

```
[array([  1,  21, 213,  32], dtype=int64),
 array([ 4,  5, 32,  3], dtype=int64),
 array([213,  23,  23,   1], dtype=int64)]
```

[image: Here's a screenshot for the same]

Comment: thanks for the help! could you explain the zip function a little bit more?

Comment: zip() is used to pack elements into tuples and iterate through the tuple. Try these two lines after the code above!

`for (col_name,np_arr) in zip(df.columns, np_arr_list):`
`       print("Column Name :", col_name,"\nArray",np_arr,"\n")` 

It binds col_name to iterate through df.columns and np_arr through np_arr_list.

I use it for association of column names and values in some use cases where I want to keep data and names separate.
Other way is to use a dictionary with keys as column name and values as numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `to_numpy()` methods because others will be deprecated. If your `pandas` library is older than **0.24** you should update it first because *this method has come after from that version*.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> arr = []
>>> for column in df.columns:
...     arr.append(df[column].to_numpy())
...
>>> arr
[array([1, 1, 4], dtype=int64), array([2, 3, 6], dtype=int64)]
>>>
```

Comment: I tried using this and I got this error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: as I said you need to update pandas package to 0.24 or newer. Latest is 0.24.2. Try print(pd.__version__) to see the current version

Comment: The one I'm working with is quite old thanks for the tip

Comment: @GgdHhdhd Be aware that all other methods like .values . as_matrix will be deprecated so I would not suggest using them